# Can someone write a very simple multi-threaded program?

Tags: multithreading

Whether it be C, C++, or Java, I don't really care...

Can someone write a really simple program so that I can get some intuition for how thread synchronization is supposed to work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this demo (in C++) and tutorial would help you.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/SynchronizedThreadNoMfc.aspx

http://www.paulbridger.com/multithreading_tutorial/